# Menu.jsx:8 Uncaught TypeError: notes.map is not a function. Whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

```
import Note from "../components/Note/Note";

/**
 * @param {object[]} notes - user notes array of objects
 */
const Menu = (notes) => {
  return (
    <>
      {notes.map((val) => (
        <Note
          key={Date.now()}
          title={val.title}
          text={val.text}
          date={val.date}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Menu;
```

export default Menu;

in theory, the component displays a list of your notes. The prop is an array of objects

Comment: `notes` is not **array**

Comment: Your name in russian. May by it is answer your question on ru.stackoverflow [Uncaught TypeError: map is not a function](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479423/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-is-not-a-function) ?

Comment: `const Menu = ({ notes }) => {` to destructure the notes property from the components props object (on the assumption that you have something like `<Menu notes={notes} />`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we pass props from parents to children. It is passed down as an **object**. So, hear **notes** is an object, which contains your array.

You can check it by **console.log(notes)**